# SetupAPI - SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty substitute?

Tags: winapi, setupapi

I need to use some SetupAPI functions in firefox extension. I need to retrieve device's friendly name. I figured it can be done by `SetupDiGetClassDevs`, `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`, `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` and `SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList`.

BUT! I imported the `setupapi.dll` and declared three of the functions - no problem. Then I found out that `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` simply isn't in the DLL at all and can only be statically linked with `setupapi.lib`. Is there any way I could substitute this function?

I cannot use WMI.

Comment: You're right, there isn't an export with that exact name. That name is actually defined in the SetupApi header, like most of the functions in the windows api that have Unicode & ANSI variants. The function is in the export table as `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW` (ordinal: 373) or `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA` (ordinal: 372).

Comment: That solved it. I messaged microsoft about the lacking documentation on that. Thanks.

Comment: I turned my comment into a real answer.

Comment: That's entirely normal, winapi functions that take a string exist in two versions.  The A version is meant for legacy code that still uses char*, the W version is for modern code that uses Unicode strings.  This gets sorted out at compile time based on the UNICODE #define.  Hopefully you don't use GetProcAddress(), at least favor the /DELAYLOAD linker option, but if you do then you have to know the real name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is indeed in SetupAPI.DLL, as I've confirmed using Dependency Walker. It's just that, it takes a character-pointer (string), it has to have two variants - one for ANSI (`A`), one for Unicode (`W`).

- `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA`
- `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW`

It is with any Windows API function - if function takes one or more of character-string as arguments, it would have two variants.

I see you are probably using `GetProcAddress` to locate it. Hence, you need to pass real name (not macro) to it. Following gets wide-variant of this function.

```
GetProcAddress(handleOfDLL, "SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW"); // Wide
```

Comment: In cases like this, where I have to use GetProcAddress, I like to use a stringize macro to generate the function name string, rather than typing it manually. That way, I not only get autocompletion and protection against typos, but also the correct A/W variant depending on how UNICODE is #defined. Something like _CRT_STRINGIZE is generally available if you're using the CRT, or you can roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there isn't an export with that exact name. That name is actually defined in the SetupApi header, like most of the functions in the Windows API that have Unicode & ANSI variants.

From SetupApi.h:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW
#else
#define SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA
#endif
```

The function is in the export table as SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW (ordinal: 373) or SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA (ordinal: 372)

I found those using `dumpbin /exports setupapi.dll`.